# VBA Range is Nothing

Tags: vba, loops, range, case

Running the code below and what I'm hoping to see as a result is to have all columns with 0s on row 27 hidden - but depending on the frequency of the data, the range for those columns to be hidden is different. Basically anything that is in a sheet that starts with Daily/monthly/weekly will have to have columns hidden, all the rest of the sheets should be left alone.
It worked on a simple workbook using an if statement (sheets starting with X vs. all other), but when I added the case statement it broke...

The line marked down with bold is the one where I get an error:
**Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error**

I'm new to this, so please feel free to suggest a good vba tutorials website/book.

```
Sub Hide_Zero_Columns()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Col_to_hide As Range
    Dim Range_to_hide As Range
    Dim X As Integer

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Worksheets(WS.Name).Activate
        With WS
        Select Case Data_Frequency_Sheets
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Daily"
            Set Range_to_hide = Range("BDV$27:CWH$27")
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Month"
            Set Range_to_hide = Range("AY$27:CO$27")
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Weekl"
            Set Range_to_hide = Range("HF$27:NN$27")
        Case Else
            Set Range_to_hide = Range("A1:B1")
        End Select
        Select Case Data_Condition
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Daily"
            X = 1
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Month"
            X = 30
        Case Left(WS.Name, 5) = "Weekl"
            X = 7
        Case Else
            X = 999
        End Select
        If X <> 999 Then
                For Each Col_to_hide In ActiveSheet.Range(Range_to_hide) '<-- Error here
                    If UCase(Col_to_hide) = 0 Then
                        Col_to_hide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Else: Col_to_hide.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    End If
                Next Col_to_hide
        End If
    End With
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registrations").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: rows and columns in the excel VBA environment are assigned numerical addresses as well.  I.e. column A is 1, B is 2 etc.  If you can specify the range with a simple case statement, try setting upper and lower boundaries of a for loop and use Columns(loopvar).Hidden = False

Comment: BTW, how huge is this spreadsheet that you're all the way into column CWH?  When I scroll to the extreme right of a new excel document, it ends at "IV"

Comment: thanks for the quick reply... it's 20MB of data - pretty big I would say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already defined a `Range`, you the problem is you are trying to evaluate: `Sheet.Range(Range)` which throws the error you are getting.

Since it appears you are wanting to iterate across the columns, all you need to do is change the line to this:

```
' Iterate across the columns in the defined range.
For Each Col_to_hide In Range_to_hide.Columns
    ' Each "Col_to_hide" will represent all cells within the column.
    MsgBox Col_to_hide.Address
```

Comment: not working :(...what's odd is that if I change this line:                             For Each Col_to_hide In ActiveSheet.Range(Range_to_hide) '<-- Error here to this                                                                                            For Each Col_to_hide In ActiveSheet.Range("AA1:AB2")
it goes pass the line...it must be something above in the case statement or where I declare the variables..

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're passing a Range object as the argument to `Activesheet.Range()` and it doesn't accept that because of the Range object's default value. It would be like doing this in the Immediate Window

```
?Range(Range("A1")).Address
```

You'll get the same error. Whereas with

```
?Range("A1").Address
```

You don't. You could do this too

```
?Range(Range("A1").Address).Address
```

So the thing is that when you don't specify a property for an object, like `Range("A1")` instead of `Range("A1").Address`, then the default property is used. The Range object is a bit strange, but in this case its default property is the Value property. So `Activesheet.Range(Range_to_hide)` is the same as `Activesheet.Range(Range_to_hide.Value)`. And if Range_to_hide is a multi-cell range, then it's Value property returns an array, which you definitely can't pass into a Range's argument.

That's the explanation, the short answer is simply to use Range_to_hide, like

```
For Each Col_to_hide in Range_to_hide.Columns
```

Why the `.Columns`. Remember when I said that the Range object was a little strange. Well, unlike most objects, it has two default properties based on the context you're using it in. Earlier, the default property was Value, but in the context of a For..Each, the default value is Cells. If you don't specify .Columns in your For..Each, then it will loop through every cell in the Range. In fact, I always specify how the range is aggregated, even if it's the default Cells.